# With a regular expression, how can I get the file's name?

Tags: regex

I've got this file here:

```
\\prdflsrvcl2.unicreprd.local\Integracao-PRD\GestaoTangiveis\APD\FW_A_enviar_correio_electronico_Imagem_(384).jpg-1-52FFN8.msg
```

With the regular expression, I want this part: `FW_A_enviar_correio_electronico_Imagem_(384).jpg-1-52FFN8.msg`

I'm using the following regex:

```
[[:alnum:]-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]*$
```

However, I get **.jpg-1-52FFN8.msg** instead of what I want.

However if the file name was without the dot before the jpg, I would get **FW_A_enviar_correio_electronico_Imagem_(384)jpg-1-52FFN8.msg** instead.

Basically, I want the filename with the extension.

Thanks.

Comment: Which regular expression engine are you using?

Comment: What is the regex flavor?

Comment: Does your programming language not have libraries specifically designed for working with paths (combining, extracting components, etc), rather than messing around with regex?

Comment: It's a regex I'm using for PL SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with following regex:

```
[^\\]+$
```

It will match all characters from the end to the first occurence of `\`.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/eJ8zG2/1

Comment: Why use a capturing group? Also, the delimiters are ``\``, not `/`

Comment: This might not work for OP since some regex flavors will not recognize this pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If not specified - I assume it's PCRE. Otherwise we'll know that later..

Comment: It works and does what I want. Just making sure and testing to see if there's no problems. Thanks :)

Comment: I barely use regex and I needed to change this expression that was already being used, that's why I was using a capturing group. Just afraid that it can cause some weird impact. You know, maintenance stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex and refer the first capturing group which is `(.*)`:

`/(?!.*\\)(.*)/g`

Match all things which is not followed by `\`

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/fI3aO0/1)